# Single Clock FIFO with Single Port RAM

Tags: verilog, ram, vlsi, asic, fifo

I wanted to make use of a single port RAM to be a single clock FIFO in verilog for an asic project , due to some constraints  i can not use the dual port RAM. My confusion is when I have to perform read and write simultaneously, I thought about using a faster clock and give 1 cycle for read another cycle for write, but that option is not preferable, in the context of my project. There is the idea of making  a system with priority for read however I am not sure how to manage the write request. If I give priority to read I might lose some write requests as well.

Thanks

Comment: The question is not clear. Single port RAM can't perform simultaneous read and write by definition.

Comment: The question in short is , in order  to save some space , how to make use of an on chip single port ram and use it as a synchronous FIFO. Thats the challenge being not able to read and write simultaneously into the Single Port RAM

Comment: Either use a single port RAM and make an arbiter to handle simultaneous read/write requests, or use a dual port RAM. You can't have the best of both worlds.

Comment: Yes ,  I thought about implementing an arbiter that gives a priority to read operations, however , I have a confusion: If I give priority a priority  read, how can I manage  the write part, should I keep the data to be written into a buffer or just disregard them ? and vice versa

Comment: depth of the buffer should be designed wisely as well, depending on read and write rates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your requirements more carefully.

- How many reads can occur on contiguous clock cycles?
- How many writes can occur on contiguous clock cycles?

If the answer to both is "just one", then all you need is a simple aribter. Do the read when requested, and if a write happens at the same time, hold it in a register until the next clock cycle — which is guaranteed to be available.

If reads or writes can occur in larger "bursts", then things get quite a bit more complicated, and you might as well bite the bullet and put in a true dual-port memory, or clock your single-port memory at twice the speed.

Comment: thanks @dave , this give me more ideas, I do have 1 read that happen within 14 cycles , the read takes 2 cycles , due to the RAM latency . and then I will be having  2 or 3 writes with 14 cycles. Using dual port ram, or having a faster clock would solve my problem , but they are 2 options that I can not use in the context of my project.

Answer (score 2):

You can use 2 single port RAM to build a synchronous FIFO. All the even address goes to RAM0, and all the odd Address goes to the RAM1.
When you want to read and write at the same cycle, make sure the address 0 are not the same.
Else you have to give priority to Wite (or Read), and wait for the next cycle